# Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Sample for Speech Synthesis

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I am trying to render SVG with viseme event and render in browser using the XML.

Facing WebSocket error code: 1007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG need be rendered in browser, the XML is to be put into the html and then browser can render it.

Here is the sample code for rendering SVG with synchronization with TTS audio:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/synthesis.html#L436